# C++ Qt5 std::stack<QTreeWidgetItem*> not working

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm parsing tree data from text file into QTreeWidget. I have following code:

```
std::stack<QTreeWidgetItem*> treeStack;

auto *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget();

std::ifstream dataFile("data.txt");
std::string lineString;
std::string itemString;
int depth;
int previousDepth = 0;

while (std::getline(dataFile, lineString)) {
    depth = 0;
    for (char c : lineString) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            ++depth;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    itemString = lineString.substr(depth);
    depth /= 2;

    auto *itemWidget = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    auto *checkbox = new QCheckBox(QString::fromStdString(itemString));
    auto *treeLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    treeLayout->setContentsMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
    treeLayout->addWidget(checkbox);
    treeLayout->addStretch();
    auto *widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setLayout(treeLayout);

    if (depth > previousDepth) {
        treeStack.push(itemWidget);
        std::cout << "PUSH" << std::endl;
    }

    if (depth == 0 || treeStack.empty()) {
        treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(itemWidget);
    } else {
        QTreeWidgetItem *itemWidgetParent = treeStack.top();
        std::cout << "GET PARENT" << std::endl;
        itemWidgetParent->addChild(itemWidget);
        std::cout << "ADDED CHILD" << std::endl;
    }

    treeWidget->setItemWidget(itemWidget, 0, widget);

    previousDepth = depth;
}
```

To explain this code:
Input data is text file with tree-like structure intended with double space between parent and child.
I'm using custom widget to render data because I will need to put two checkboxes on single line.
My idea is to hold current tree-path of parents in a stack.

My problem is that this program freezes at line `itemWidgetParent->addChild(itemWidget);` and I don't understand why.

Comment: can you show example input? and how do you determine that your program "freezes" at this specific line? what compiler/IDE/environment are you using - maybe it crashes, and just shows you this line in the call stack as where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `previousDepth` to 0.
`depth` is also 0 for the first element.
But your check for whether to push the current element to the stack is `depth > previousDepth`.
So the it is never pushed onto the stack.

I suppose your program doesn't "freeze", but actually crash with a segmentation fault, since `treeStack` is empty and the result from .top() therefore probably `nullptr` or uninitialized/undefined - haven't tested.